# Can I add a JNDI Binding with a customized name for inject a Stateless Bean on my client Servlet?

Tags: servlets, ejb, jndi, java-ee-6, inject

In one hand, I have a Stateless EJB Bean which implements a remote interface.

```
    @Stateless(name = "ejbBean")
    @Remote(TimedBean.class)
    public class TimedBeanImpl implements TimedBean
    ...
```

On the other hand, I have a Servlet client where I need to inject this EJB bean for invoking its operations. The injection referts to a JNDI automatically generated by the server:

```
public class LoadTimer implements ServletContextListener {
    // EAR Local Mapping - EAR Dev Mapping
    // @EJB(mappedName = "java:global/appTest/appTestModuleOne-01.00.00/ejbBean")
    @EJB(mappedName = "java:global/appTest-01.00.00/appTestModuleOne-01.00.00/ejbBean")
    private TimedBean timedBean;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletcontextevent) {
...
```

It works.

But the fact of referencing the jndi automatically generated makes the solution highly dependent on the specific environment:

- It depends on the server. For example, my local server for testing it's a JBOSS 7.1 and my dev server it's a JBOSS EAP 6.2, and the automatically generated jndi's are different.
- It depends on the packaging. Not is the same refers to the ejbBean deploying in a EAR file than in a WAR file.
- And it depends on the version of artifacts. More changes.

I want, if possible, is to specify a unique name for the bean can be referred to the servlet in each server, for each version and packaging, in order not to have to be making continuous changes in development and avoid errors in deployments.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<application-name>` in application.xml and `<module-name>` in your module descriptor (web.xml or ejb-jar.xml) to mitigate the hardcoded version numbers.  (Note that as of EE 6, you should use `@EJB(lookup="...")` rather mappedName.)  The spec also requires that your application server give you an option to override the lookup name of the `@EJB` reference while deploying the application, so it should not matter what is hardcoded in your application at development time.

Comment: Thanks for the response @bkail. The truth is that he had not reviewed the lookup attribute. I take into account. In addition to these mechanisms you described to mitigate the problem, I discovered that if I use the notation ejb no arguments also recovered an instance of the bean. I understand that this solution is not valid if more than one implementation of the remote interface, and besides that, I would know how to do the lookup by defect. I will continue investigating.